# Can I use Sentence-Bert to embed event triples?

Tags: natural-language-processing, bert, embeddings, information-retrieval

I extracted event triples from sentences using OpenIE. Can I concatenate the components in the event triple to make it a sentence and use Sentence-Bert to embed the event?
It seems no one has done this way before so I am questioning my idea.

Answer (score 0):

Sentence-Bert can embed any chain of characters in english and create semantically related embeddings (or at least contextual character-based if the model is dealing with OOV).
Even if no one else did it before, you can do it !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).